# Fast build but slow start in Vite + Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm migrating a Vue application from Webpack to Vite.

I started fixing all the errors that Vite said. Now the build is really fast and is done in just a few milliseconds and I don't get any errors.

[image]

Now, when I go to the browser, it loads for around 2 minutes or more until it shows something. If I open the network tab in the developer's tool, I see all the components trying to load and they're pending for around 2 minutes like I said before:

[image]

Here is my vite configuration:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      '~bootstrap': resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap')
    }
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
        @import "@/assets/styles/base.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Did you experience something similar? There is something that I'm not doing well? Can I do something to improve my Vite configuration?

After that, the hot reloading works pretty fast.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Slow when doing `npm run build` + `npm run preview`, or slow when doing `npm run dev`?

Comment: @JoséRamírez I wasn't clear, sorry. When I run `npm run dev` is fast (see first image), but then I go to the browser and I have to wait 2 minutes until all the components load (see 2nd image)

Comment: you should pre-bundle bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is on-demand compilation of the CSS.  You are using Bootstrap raw (in SCSS form), not compiled.  SASS is particularly "slow", or maybe not slow, but notorious compared to other tasks done when building.

Vite, when run via `npm run dev`, doesn't actually compile or build or bundle anything.  This is why it starts so fast.  However, the first HTTP request that requires CSS will trigger the SASS compiler, and this takes a "long time" for something like Bootstrap.  This is normal behavior.  You don't have a problem here.